# Woocommerce email notifications and emails settings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

[image]

I noticed that you can set recipient list in woocommerce email settings page. I've added some custom emails for the site I'm building but I couldn't figure out how to send email to the customer instead of specifying an email.

Some default woocommerce emails have "Customer" as recipients like the screenshot above.

Can we make some custom emails to do same thing?

How can we set the recipients in either PHP or on settings page so that the email sends to customer instead of my own email?

In the settings I see a field to enter recipients as below:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You need to set the `customer_email` parameter `true` in your email class' constructor. See the [customer invoice](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/1b2df3dd3b02e836286b899f858687e33fc0d5aa/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-invoice.php#L57) email for an example.